# Calculate age on integer field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The date field I have to calculate age on is `yyyymmdd`.

I've tried below and converted `getdate` to `yyyymmdd` format but can't seem to get the age from that. I've tried with `datediff` but can't seem to get it to work either.

```
 SELECT CLAIM.BTHDAT
     , (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(), 112) - CLAIM.BTHDAT)/365.25   
 FROM CLAIM
```

Comment: Now if you stored your DOB using a `date` datatype everything would be so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want AGE in YEARS...  How about `datediff()`

```
Select Age = datediff(YEAR,left(CLAIM.BTHDAT,8),getdate())
 From  CLAIM
```

Comment: Color me surprised that this works.  I didn't think datediff would take yyyymmdd as a string.  In theory, the left() clause is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
SELECT CLAIM.BTHDAT, DATEDIFF(hour,CLAIM.BTHDAT,GETDATE())/8766.0 AS AgeYearsDecimal
    ,CONVERT(int,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,CLAIM.BTHDAT,GETDATE())/8766.0,0)) AS AgeYearsIntRound
    ,DATEDIFF(hour,CLAIM.BTHDAT,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc  FROM CLAIM
```

If you want to Age in Day,Month & year then you can try this.Create Function to Calcuate Age and call it in Query like this

```
    Create function [dbo].[GetAge](@dayOfBirth datetime, @today datetime)
       RETURNS varchar(100)
    AS

    Begin
      DECLARE @tmpdate datetime, @date datetime, @years int, @months int, @days int

    SELECT @tmpdate = @dayOfBirth

    SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, @today) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@tmpdate) > MONTH(@today)) OR (MONTH(@tmpdate) = MONTH(@today) AND DAY(@tmpdate) > DAY(@today)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate)
    SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(m, @tmpdate, @today) - CASE WHEN DAY(@tmpdate) > DAY(@today) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(m, @months, @tmpdate)
    SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(d, @tmpdate, @today)

    return cast(@years as varchar(2)) + ' years,' + cast(@months as varchar(2)) + ' months,' + cast(@days as varchar(3)) + ' days'
    end


Select  CLAIM.BTHDAT,dbo.[GetAge](CLAIM.BTHDAT,getdate()) From CLAIM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option to get the age accurately, with the assumption that all dates will follow the `yyyymmdd` format and will be valid dates.

```
SELECT CLAIM.BTHDAT
 ,DATEDIFF( YY, CONVERT(CHAR(8),CLAIM.BTHDAT), GETDATE()) 
   - CASE WHEN SUBSTRING( CONVERT( char(8), GETDATE(), 112), 5, 4) < SUBSTRING( CONVERT( char(8), BTHDAT), 5, 4)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 FROM CLAIM
```